# Gradient of the variance of a Gaussian process

Tags: stochastic-processes, gaussian-process, bayesian-optimization

I'm trying to compute the spatial derivatives of the [expected improvement](http://ash-aldujaili.github.io/blog/2018/02/01/ei/) acquisition function in Gaussian-process optimisation, and doing so requires the spatial derivatives of the predictive posterior mean and variance.

[This note on "differentiating Gaussian processes"](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/mchutchon/DifferentiatingGPs.pdf) gives expressions for the gradient of the posterior mean, and the variance of that gradient, but not the gradient of the variance of the mean.

Does anyone have a reference for calculating the spatial derivatives of the variance?

Thanks!